# In Angular, my searchbar doesn't work properly

Tags: angular, routes, searchbar

I've tried to implement a searchbar in a `Mybooklist` page, so I have two components, `DisplayBooks` and `Detail`, while the searchbar works fine on the displaybooks page, it doesn't work on the detail page, it's only working once when on the `DisplayBooks` it opens the detail page, and then it will not open another detail page anymore. I want it to be able to navigate in between detail pages.

Help is appreciated!

Here's the code for the search bar. HTML:

```
<div class="search-bar" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px;">
    <input
      type="text"
      [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"
      (input)="filterBooks()"
      placeholder="Search by title"
    />
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="filterBooks()">Cerca</button>
  
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let book of filteredBooks">
        <a [routerLink]="['/detail', book.id]">{{book.title}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

search.bar. TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Book } from '../book';
import { BookServiceService } from '../book-service.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-bar',
  templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.scss']
})

export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {
  books: Book[] = [];
  filteredBooks: Book[] = [];
  searchTerm: string = '';

  constructor(private bookServiceService: BookServiceService, private router: Router) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.bookServiceService.getBooks().subscribe(books => {
      this.books = books;
      this.filteredBooks = this.books;
    });
  }

  filterBooks() {
    if (!this.searchTerm) {
      this.filteredBooks = this.books;
    } else {
      this.filteredBooks = this.books.filter(book =>
        book.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  }


  goToBook(book: Book) {
    this.router.navigate(['detail', book.id]);
  }
}
```

I've tried to implement OnSameUrlNavigation, but I am not sure if I've done it properly as I implemented it on the app.routing